# Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in .... localhost:3000/* errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vagrant, webpacker

### system:

Ruby: ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
Rails: Rails 6.0.2
OS: Windows to a VM (vagrant ssh -> to ubuntu machine : Linux vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 3.13.0-170-generic #220-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux

when I run rails server -b 0.0.0.0 I can access localhost:3000 and see the **Yay! You’re on Rails!**

but when I attempt to navigate to localhost:3000/say/hello
the below error comes up in browser

## Browser error:

```
Showing /files_on_your_computer/rails6tut/demo/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #9 raised:

Webpacker can't find application in /files_on_your_computer/rails6tut/demo/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
Extracted source (around line #9):
7
8
9
10
11
12
              

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>

Rails.root: /files_on_your_computer/rails6tut/demo
```

## console error:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/files_on_your_computer/rails6tut/demo$ rails server -b 0.0.0.0                                    => Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.2 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.1 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/say/hello" for 10.0.2.2 at 2019-12-17 17:51:09 +0000
   (1.5ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by SayController#hello as HTML
  Rendering say/hello.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered say/hello.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 4.3ms | Allocations: 271)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 115ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 7431)



ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in /files_on_your_computer/rails6tut/demo/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}
):
     6:     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
     7:
     8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
     9:     <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    10:   </head>
    11:
    12:   <body>

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9
Started GET "/" for 10.0.2.2 at 2019-12-17 17:54:56 +0000
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (Duration: 3.1ms | Allocations: 190)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 899)
```

I have seen some similar issues on heroku, but i am running this locally so I am a bit confuddled.
I am following the Agile Web Development with rails 6 book.

Comment: How are you running Webpack? And what does your `config/webpacker.yml` look like?

Comment: So, I created a new rails app in a different directory (one not linked between the VM and my machine) and now everything works as expected. If someone can provide a more technical explanation as to why it didnt work in the shared directory between my machines I would appreaciate it very much.

Comment: hmmm I was using the symbolic linked directory because I was using my editor (atom).  by moving to a new app within the virtual machine, i fixed webpacker errors, but now I am at a loss as to how I can use my editor on my host machine to access the files on the virtual machine :/

Comment: The error shows you 4 possible cuases of the error, have you checked if any of that is happening to you?

Comment: @arieljuod I have. And I don't think it's any of those 4 errors because rails server runs without the routing error in the VM when it's not in a shared folder. I have identified the problem to find it's the shared folder, now I'm just wondering why

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, I was using the latest version of node  `v15.2.0` and switched to a lower version of node `v14.8.0` and webpacker is working fine.

Reference: [https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2779#issuecomment-727170370]

Comment: problem was my node version that was 16. now shift to 12 solve the problem

Answer (score -3):

What I did here simply is comment out line number 9.

```
8:<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

9:<%#= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem, only postpones it :)

Comment: @MarkBoulder ,  I agree, it only postpones it